# QGIS hidden behind Windows toolbar (bottom)

Tags: qgis-3, windows-10

I'm running QGIS 3.10.6, Windows 10, just downloaded in order to try to alleviate this minor but irritating issue. The bottom of the window of QGIS is repeatedly hiding itself behind the standard Windows toolbar at the bottom of the screen. Of course this renders the Coordinate, Scale, etc commands unavailable. I've experimented with the various options in View, getting stuck in full screen mode in the process, but none seem to fix this issue. QGIS appears to want the whole screen. The program appears to crash fairly often when attempting to resize, so it is difficult to resolve this issue.

Comment: try to put it in full screen and back to normal view (press F11 twice).  Try to reduce the window size, close QGIS, then re-open and maximize it again

Comment: F11 successfully places the view into full screen, but pressing F11 again does not return it to normal screen. In addition, having reloaded QGIS all the panels and toolbars are switched off as default.

Comment: ?? F11 should work for putting/removing the full screen. Make sure QGis has the focus

Comment: Seems to be my keyboard set up. F11 reduces my screen brightness no matter what focus.

Comment: I faced the same issue. When I closed all docked panels on the right side of the screen I had it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

Every time someone encounters a GUI problem with QGIS, simply uninstalling won't do the trick as corrupted GUI files are located in the profile folder, which isn't removed when uninstalling QGIS. To test this, try creating a new QGIS profile to see if it improves your GUI issue. If you want to fix your current profile, you can do so by retracing your steps; for me, it was a corrupted plugin that, after uninstallation, restored the functionality of my QGIS GUI.